# Rust can not infer type for Sub<RHS=Self> trait type of RHS. Why?

Tags: rust

I am currently implementing the Sub trait for my custom newtypes, which add some compile-time safety mechanisms. I tried to implement the Sub trait for my new types, but they do not work without ugly casts. Here is what I have ( note I am working with ndarray, and before you recommend nalgebra, no I can not use nalgebra because I need fast matrix multiplications ) :

```rust
use cauchy::Scalar;
use ndarray_linalg::Lapack;
use nalgebra::Dim;
use ndarray::{Dimension, ArrayBase, OwnedRepr, Data};
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct States<A, N, D, R> where
    A: Scalar + Lapack,
    N: Dim,
    D: Dimension,
    R: Data<Elem=A>
{
    pub(in super) _dim_phantom: PhantomData<N>,
    pub(in super) data: ArrayBase<R, D>
}
```

And here I have my implementation of the Sub trait :

```rust
impl<'a, A, N, M, R1, R2> Sub<&'a States<A, N, Ix3, R1>> for &States<A, M, Ix2, R2> where
    A: Scalar + Lapack,
    N: Dim,
    M: Dim,
    R1: Data<Elem=A>,
    R2: Data<Elem=A>,
    ShapeConstraint: DimEq<M,N>
{
    type Output = States3<A, N>;

    fn sub(self, rhs: &'a States<A, N, Ix3, R1>) -> Self::Output {
        let mut out = self.data.view().insert_axis(Axis(0)).to_owned();
        out.sub_assign(&rhs.data);
        States {
            _dim_phantom: Default::default(),
            data: out
        }
    }
}
```

Now the following does not work (note that `DimEq<N,M>` is satisfied in method where this snippet is used:

```rust
let states: &States<A, N, Ix2, OwnedRepr<A>> = ...
let innovations_updated: States<A, M, Ix3, OwnedRepr<A>> = ...
let output = states - &innovations_updated
```

For the code above I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/filter/kalman.rs:71:39
   |
35 | impl<T, S, M> Filter<T, S, M> for KalmanFilter<T, S, M> where
   |         - expected type parameter
...
57 |     fn update<N, Q>(&self, states: &States2<T, N>, covariances: &Covariances<T, N>, measurements: &States2<T, Q>) -> Self::Update
   |               - found type parameter
...
71 |         let updated_states = states - &innovation_updates;
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `S`, found type parameter `N`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&States<T, S, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 3]>, _>`
              found reference `&States<T, N, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 3]>, OwnedRepr<T>>`
   = note: a type parameter was expected, but a different one was found; you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

But when I use convoluted casts, then it works as follows:

```rust
let states: &States<A, N, Ix2, OwnedRepr<A>> = ...
let innovations_updated: States<A, M, Ix3, OwnedRepr<A>> = ...
let output = <&States2<T, N> as Sub<&States<T, N, ndarray::Ix3, OwnedRepr<T>>>>::sub(states, &innovation_updates);
```

Now this is confusing to me, because the IDE manages to annotate the line with correct output type. Further neither of the variables have anything to do with type parameter S. Why does it want something from type parameter `S` ?

Comment: I think rust should catch up those annotations, maybe its an small error could you create an minimal reproducible example, when i face this kind of issues with traits when i start creating a minimal example of the error I find where was the error

Comment: I could do that, will try in any case. It is really confusing why it is expecting some type parameter S out of blue.